# Can't connect to APNS

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

Does anyone know if it's possible to connect to APN via IP-adressed instead of via URL? Or do they use round robin?

In that case, what is the adresses for the push and feedback services (prod. and sandbox).

Thankful for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about round-robin IP addresses, but why do you want to use them? By resolving them with DNS you are independent from changing IP adresses:

- Sandbox: `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com`
- Production `gateway.push.apple.com`

Comment: Well, im not allowed to open the firewall for URL:s

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use ip addresses. but we should avoid the risk that apple change the server address. domain name is fixed. so please use the domain name as possible as you can.